# Laravel tries to render layout instead of returning png file

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have this weird issue with Laravel 5.1. When I access a png file without /public before it (e.g. 127.0.0.1/file.png) Laravel renders the file correctly. But when I put public in front of it (e.g. 127.0.0.1/public/file.png), Laravel tries to render a layout. The file is located inside the public folder.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use this:
src="{{ url('images/file.png') }}"? url() creates the correct path (public).

Comment: Is your website root/home `http://127.0.0.1/` OR `http://127.0.0.1/public/`?

Comment: @matthiku: The application is deployed on a shared server. I tried your suggestion but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Jonathon: The Document Root is pointing at public folder.

Comment: If your DocumentRoot is pointing at your `public` directory, then isn't what you're describing expected behaviour? I.e. Accessing `http://127.0.0.1/image.png` should point to a file located at `/your/path/public/image.png` and attempting to access `http://127.0.0.1/public/image.png` would be like trying to access a file located at `/your/path/public/public/image.png

Comment: @Jonathon: Sorry I didn't explain this better. My application is deployed on a shared server (Document Root pointing at public folder) and when I try to access the image, Laravel tries to render a layout instead of an image. On my local VM, accessing the image without /public in front works, but if I put /public in front of it, it also tries to render a layout instead of showing the image.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I had to change the folder permissions to 755 and it worked.